# hex to text conversion failing in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had a .RData file downloaded from Recount2 and was using below code to convert and read the data in the file

```
hexToText <- function(msg){
  hex <- sapply(seq(1, nchar(as.character(msg)), by=2), 
                function(x) substr(msg, x, x+1))
  hex <- subset(hex, !hex == "00")
  gsub('[^[:print:]]+', '', rawToChar(as.raw(strtoi(hex, 16L))))
}
```

This code was working when using the code on local R Studio and the file stored in S3 bucket

Moment I uploaded the code in EC2 and the data still residing in S3 bucket, the same code is not working. I am i missing anything

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to share the exact error you are getting and the environment details of R from your RStudio and EC2 instance.

One possible reason could be that you have difference version of packages on local RStudio and EC2 instance.